# Increasing Page Height With Javascript

Tags: javascript

I dont know anything about javascript but I want to be able to click on an Image and increase the page size.

Example. A 500px x 500px box with an image in it. When you click on an image the box will increase to 500px x 1000px with new content within the new area without it changing the page.

How would I do this?

Like On This Website
http://kyanmedia.com/
Click on the earth worm at the bottom

Comment: How does it "increase" from 500x500 to 500x100?

Comment: 100px is smaller than 500px... Did you mean 1000px?

Comment: Um Yes I Did Lol

I want it like on this website 
http://kyanmedia.com/
Click the earty worm at the bottom

Comment: Im not doing good today. I mean earth worm lol

Answer (score 2):

you can have an element down at the bottom of the page

```
<div id="extraDiv" style="display:none"> some extra stuff </div>
```

and using javascript, do a

```
document.getElementById("extraDiv").style.display = "block";
```

to make the page longer.  If you want animation, then you can use jQuery, scriptaculous, or other javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to accomplish this, which would have the cool scroll rather than it just popping up. Have you're main content in a div, then the content you want to show in a hidden div, like:

```
<div>Main Content</div>
<div id="hiddenLab" style="display:none">Content to show</div>
```

You would then use the jQuery [slideToggle](http://docs.jquery.com/Effects/slideToggle) command to slide it up and down, something like:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#hidden").click(function(){
                $("#about").slideToggle("slow");
            });
        });     
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #maincontent { width:100%; height:100px;background:green} 
        #about { width:100%; height:1000px;display:none;background:red;} 
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="maincontent">
        <a id="hidden" href="#">Click to see hidden</a> 
    </div> 
    <div id="about">Content to show</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: The jQuery command goes inside your Javascript.  jQuery is just a javascript library.  To get the above code to run add an element (image, link etc) with an id="earthWorm", the above code will fire on the click of that element.
Check out these videos (http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/) for a quick overview of jQuery if you're interested, it's real easy to learn and you can do some real nice things with it.

Comment: I cant get this to work.

The Script is: 
<script type="application/javascript">
$("hidden").click(){
$("about").slideToggle("slow";
});
</script>

The HTML is:

<body>
<div id="maincontent">
<center>
<br />
<a href="index.html"><img src="Keiron Lowe.png" alt="Keiron Lowe"/></a>
<img src="Keiron Lowe.png" id="hidden" />
<br />
<br />
<img src="Seperator.png"/>
</div>
<div id="about" style="display:none">Content to show</div>
</body>

And the CSS is: 


#maincontent {
width:auto;
height:1000px;
}

#about {
width:auto;
height:1000px;
}

help?

Comment: Have you included the jQuery .js file?

Comment: Re-read your code there, try $("about").slideToggle("slow"); not $("about").slideToggle("slow"; }); or even try putting in an alert() to see if the click code is firing.

Comment: Nahh Still Not Working 

HTML And Script.: 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jQuery.js" />
<script type="application/javascript"> $("hidden").click(){ $("about").slideToggle("slow"); </script>
</head>

<body> 
<div id="maincontent"> 
<center>
<br /> 
<a href="index.html"><img src="Keiron Lowe.png" alt="Keiron Lowe"/></a>
<img src="Keiron Lowe.png" id="hidden" />
<br /> 
<br /> 
<img src="Seperator.png"/> 
</div> 
<div id="about" style="display:none">Content to show</div> 

CSS:

#maincontent {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#about {
width:auto; 
height:1000px; 
}